# Using jQuery how to select each td in a tr, table by table

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my interface I have multiple tables. I want to go to each “td” in a “tr” table by table. If I use this way, code can’t identify tables,

```
$(function() {
    $('tr').each(function() {
        // For each row
        $(this).find('td').each(function(i) {
           // code to be execute 
        });
        
    });
});
```

It works like this, execute first column in all tables and then go to second column.
I want to do this, execute first column in first table then go to second column in first table and execute second table as first table

**This is happens with above code**
[image: This is happens with above code]

**This is what I want to do**
[image: This is what I want to do]

Can someone please help me to do that, thank you...

Comment: Why don't you start with `$('table').each(...)` then with `tr` and `td`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this using the index of table and column

```js
$(function() {
  $('table').each(function(ind) {
    $(this).find('tr').each(function() {
      $(this).find('td').each(function(i) {
        $(this).text(ind * 2 + i + 1);
      });
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also You can do the following if column count is different

```js
$(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $('table').each(function(ind) {
    $table = $(this);
    $(this).find('tr:first').each(function() {
      $(this).find('td').each(function(i1) {
        $table.find('tr td:nth-child(' + (i1 + 1) + ')').text(i++);
      });
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector to select each td. `$("tr td").each(fn...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested each like:

```
$(function() {
    $('table').each(function() {

        $(this).find('tr').each(function(i) {
               $(this).find('td').each(function(i) {
                        // code to be execute 
                });
        });

    });
})
```

;